# Remove Scientific representation of double value without converting the variable datatype to String in Java

Tags: java, json, double, decimalformat, scientific-notation

I need to write some double values to a Json file

```
double number = 24910098.356;
```

It is written to Json file as below
2.4910098356E7
but want it to be displayed as 24910098.356.

I tried DecimalFormat but it is converting the value to String, but I want it to be a double value even after fomatting since it is part of requirement.

Comment: If it is written to a file and you can read it when you print the file, it is a string (regardless of whether it has quotes around it).  It seems to me  you want it written out without the quotes so the JSON will interpret it correctly when it's parsed, yes?  You should include a [mre] to show what you are doing.

Comment: The json file will be read and processed further by the client, so they want it to be a double value. Since they don't want to do any conversions from their end.

Comment: You still need to show how you are doing this.  And show what you expect and what you are getting after creating the file.  And keep the example short.